# install sun java 6 and sun java 7 side-by-side on linux (fedora 16) using rpm

Tags: linux, java, rpm, sun-java6-jdk, fedora-16

This is what I would like to achieve, but I'm failing (I'm a newbie in Linux).

I have a Fedora 16 box (64 bit) and would like to install multiple versions of oracle java (java 6 and java 7 for the moment).
I'm trying to install java using the rpm software and I would like to install both of them under `/opt`.

I downloaded the required packages from the Oracle site:

```
jdk-6u30-linux-x64-rpm.bin
jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm
```

and extracted the rpm package from inside the `.bin` file running

```
./jdk-6u30-linux-x64-rpm.bin -x
```

obtaining the following situation:

```
jdk-6u30-linux-amd64.rpm
jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm
```

Then I looked inside `jdk-6u30-linux-amd64.rpm`  with:

```
rpm -qpl ~/Downloads/jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm
```

and obtained that java 6 will install its files into:

```
/etc                   (some files)
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0\_30 (the majority of the files)
```

In a similar way java 7 will install into:

```
/etc
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0\_02
```

Because I want to install into `/opt` I tried to install using *rpm relocation*.
Both packages seem to be rpm-relocatable, in fact:

```
rpm -qpi ~/Downloads/jdk-6u30-linux-amd64.rpm | grep -i reloc
```

gives as result

```
Relocations : /usr/java
```

and

```
rpm -qpi ~/Downloads/jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm | grep -i reloc
```

gives as result

```
Relocations : /usr/java
```

### Attempt 1 (install java 6 and then java 7)

```
sudo rpm -i --relocate /usr/java=/opt/java ~/Downloads/jdk-6u30-linux-amd64.rpm
```

this runs almost smoothly because rpm says

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/java/jdk1.6.0\_30': No such file or directory`

rpm -q jdk
```

says

```
jdk-1.6.0\_30-fcs.x86\_64_ ... OK!
```

then

```
sudo rpm -i --relocate /usr/java=/opt/java ~/Downloads/jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm
```

fails tremendously saying:

```
file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of
jdk-2000:1.7.0\_02-fcs.x86\_64*     conflicts with file from package
jdk-2000:1.6.0\_30-fcs.x86\_64*
```

### Attempt 2 (install java 7 and then java 6)

having yet installed java 6 I'll remove it first:

```
sudo rpm -e jdk*
sudo rpm -q jdk*
```

gives:

```
package jdk is not installed* <- OK, uninstalled!
```

then let's try installing java 7

```
sudo rpm -i --relocate /usr/java=/opt/java ~/Downloads/jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm*
```

gives the usual error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02': No such file or directory`*
```

and now java 6

```
sudo rpm -i --relocate /usr/java=/opt/java ~/Downloads/jdk-6u30-linux-amd64.rpm*
```

fails saying two things:

```
package jdk-2000:1.7.0\_02-fcs.x86\_64 (which is newer than jdk-2000:1.6.0\_30-fcs.x86\_64) is already installed*
```

and

```
file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-2000:1.6.0\_30-fcs.x86\_64
conflicts with file from package jdk-2000:1.7.0\_02-fcs.x86\_64*
```

My questions are:

1. symbolic link creation problem:
   is there a way to fix it? the installation process seems not to be aware that I
   tried to use
   the relocation mechanism, even if the package is relocatable (as far as I see)
2. am I missing something in the installation process? Is it really possible to have both java 6 and java 7
   on the same Linux machine? How? What am I doing wrong?
3. Is there another way to achieve my goal?

PS: this is my first question here. I apologize in advance if something is wrong (from my English to the formatting and anything)
PS2: I tried to add the tag *sun-java7-jdk* to this question but I haven't enough reputation to do it... should this tag be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problems getting Oracle java and OpenJDK to exist side by side on Fedora 16. I followed the guide on [If not True then False](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Could you summarize the article here? We prefer you don't just link articles here.

Answer (score 14):

This is the more simple way, when you get this error:

```
package jdk.... (which is newer than jdk...) is already installed
```

Use the `--force` flag to install multiple versions.

So for example:

```
sudo rpm -ivh --force jdk-6u35-linux-amd64.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

`jdk-7u2-linux-x64.rpm` is newer than `jdk-6u30-linux-amd64.rpm` and the RPM package management tool is smart enough to overwrite it with the newer release.

The easiest way to install sun java 6 and sun java 7 side-by-side is to download the Java tarballs from Oracle and extract them into `/opt`

Answer (score 1):

I think Dejan is correct about installing the Java tarballs instead of the RPM. If you set up your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` correctly most uses will not need the additional setup that the RPM installation gives you (see [this page for details of what jexec actually does](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6211008)).

One problem might be that some versions of the JDK do not make a tarball (`*.tar.gz`) available but instead just give you a `*-rpm.bin` and a `*.bin`. In this case the `*.bin` file is actually just a self extracting archive that results in the usual JAVA_HOME directory when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

To install Java Runtime Environment on Fedora, Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, etc.

```
# yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

To intall package to developing programs using Java on Fedora, Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, etc.

```
# yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

from http://namhuy.net/1195/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-7.html